# How to replace the exact word in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, replace

I have this query:

```
UPDATE tbl SET fldname = replace(fldname,'St','Stats');
```

However if anything begins with the letters St, such as Stump, it would then look like Statsump. How can I just have the St replaced with the exact match? Thanks!

Comment: So the field has to be exactly St? `SET fldname='Stats' WHERE fldname='St'`

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK MySQL does not directly support regexp replacing (http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=27389), unless you use [user defined functions](https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp).

You could try adding a `WHERE char_length(`fldname`) == 5`, though - this would match only the strings of length 5, and the only string of length 5 containing `'Stats'` is... `'Stats'`.

Or of course ditch the whole thing and just do `SET fldname='St' WHERE fldname == 'Stats'`, which would probably be the sane thing to do unless your query is more complex than your example.

Comment: actually MySQL support regexp and like syntax, see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

Comment: Looks like the best solution is to query from php and use regex to clean up. Im basically just cleaning up a lot of garbage data someone left behind, there are a lot of rows though so was looking for a query level solution. Oh well.

Comment: @John: what's wrong with `WHERE`? It certainly *is* a query-level solution :)

Comment: @Tobia Tesan because the field is not exactly St. It could be at the beginning of the word or at the end of a word.

Comment: Sorry, John, I fear I misunderstood your question, then - you want to replace *all* occurrences of "St" (or some string) wherever they occur?